# Let $X_i$ for $i=1,2,3,.....$ be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables over [0,1].

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, ...,$X_n$  be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables over $[0,1]$. Define $$N=min[n\geq1:X_1+X_2+...+X_n\gt1]$$
Find $P(N>n)$ and $E[N]$.

Here is my clue:
Here I found out that N is discrete r.v.
$$P(N=1)=P(X_1\gt1)=0$$
$$P(N=2)=P(X_1+X_2\gt1|X_1\lt1)$$
$$P(N=3)=P(X_1+X_2+X_3\gt1|X_1+X_2\lt1)$$
$$P(N=n)=P(X_1+X_2+...+X_n\gt1|X_1+X_2+...+X_{n-1}\lt1)$$
But I have trouble calculating these probabilities. Am I on the right track?

Comment: So far, so good. In principle, you could now calculate $P(N> n)$ as $1$ minus the sum of these first $n$ terms, but they are tricky. Hint: What do you know about the sum of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ when $N > n$? can you use this to find an easier way to calculate $P(N> n)$?

Comment: @Furrer I don't really get it. $P(N\gt n)=1-\sum iP(N=i)$ is this what you mean? But how could I calculate the conditional probability?

Comment: @Furrer is the sum of Xi always greater than 1 when $N\gt n$?

Comment: When $N>n$, the first $n$ terms are yet to reach $1$ ($N$ is the smallest number for which this happens). So the event $N>n$ is identical to $X_1+\cdots+X_n <= 1$.

Comment: $P\{N=2\}=P\{X_1 \leq 1,X_1+X_2 >1\}$. It is not a conditional probability as you have stated.